# Stopping Meteor autorun in template subscriptions?

Tags: meteor

I'm making an order form and I want the user to be able to resume their order at a later time, so I create an order in an `IncompleteOrders` collection and save the `docId` of the incomplete order in the user's LocalStorage.

When the user returns to the page I want to read the `docId` stored in their LocalStorage, subscribe to the `IncompleteOrders` collection, and query for their incomplete order.

```
Template.order.onCreated(function(){

  if (amplify.store('orders') && amplify.store('orders').docId){

    //old order ID found in user's Local Storage
    let docId = amplify.store('orders').docId;
    let instance = this;

    instance.autorun(function(){

      let subscription = this.subscribe('incompleteOrders');

      if(subscription.ready()){
        console.log('IncompleteOrders subscription complete!');
        Session.set('orderContents', IncompleteOrders.findOne(docId));
      };

    });

  } else {

    //no old order found, no need to subscribe to IncompleteOrders collection
    Session.set('orderContents', {});

  };

};
```

The problem is that the `orderContents` session variable gets changed in other parts of the code, and since it's a reactive data source, it always re-runs the `autorun` function, subscribes again, and re-runs the `Session.set` portion inside of my `onCreated` callback.

Is there a more intelligent way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use c.stop() where c is a callback. Please go through code below it should help

```
instance.autorun(function(c){

  let subscription = this.subscribe('incompleteOrders');

  if(subscription.ready()){
    console.log('IncompleteOrders subscription complete!');
    Session.set('orderContents', IncompleteOrders.findOne(docId));
    c.stop()
  };

});
```

Thanks

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. Link to docs: https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, how about doing it on router, i.e; when the router changes and the form isn't submitted but has some data than insert the available fields into incomplete collection?

Comment: Say that the user browses directly to `mypage/order`. What happens in the router? I don't think the router's `waitOn` section is a good place to be reading a user's browser's `LocalStorage` data and writing all the logic for whether or not to subscribe to the `IncompleteOrders` collection.